# Facebook app URL issues error message - [canvas url / domain error]

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

After chatting with my hosting company Webhero, I googled for an answer, found similar issues on Stackoverflow, tried their solutions and ended up creating this account to see if I could get an answer.

Here is the issue - 
I have a site Afrifacti.com and would like the 'facebook' button to post a status of the currently loaded quote to a users Facebook profile.

I've set up the app on Facebook dev -> app settings -> basic
and typed afrifacti.com into the "App domains" input field.

Here is the error - http://cl.ly/TggW

I have this site hosted as a subdirectory of planetlucid.com. I also tried
planetlucid.com/afrifacti.com (with and without Http or Https)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Ry

Comment: `planetlucid.com/afrifacti.com` is not a domain name.

Comment: * I also tried afrifacti.com by itself (with and without Http or Https). That didn't work either.

Comment: For just a like button you don’t need to set app domain. _If_ you want to set it, then you have to fill out one of the other fields mentioned in the error message.

Comment: @CBroe Its going to be more of a post this caption/quote button. Any tips on what I'd do for that?

Answer (score 0):

clear the field with the error message. Press the big add button and put the domain in there.

It has to be a domain. folders don't count.

Comment: Thanks. that got me alot closer. strange that they'd put that below the item when it's something that users need to do first. I added the URL and then scrolled up to add the domain. the button only works with one of my accounts. 1 - Signed into my main facebook account -  but it doesn't have the quote - http://cl.ly/Tkjj -
2 - Signed into my other facebook account - it doesnt post anything - http://cl.ly/TkhL